# How can i use {allowDiskUse: true} in findAll() query in spring data mongo?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

For example, i want get list of obejects where i got the exception : **"com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 292 and error message 'Executor error during find command :: caused by :: Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting."**

i found some solution from stackoverflow, they are suggesting in aggregate query where they used  **{allowDiskUse: true}**. but i want to know is there any way possible that i can use crudRepo.findAll() with that particular condition.

Answer (score 0):

In file repository. We can use

```
@Aggregation(pipeline = {"{'$sort':{'name':-1}}"})
@Meta(allowDiskUse = true)
List<T> findAll();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).